# S3 photo id issue

Tags: amazon-s3

model: 1

```
class PromotionPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_attached_file :photo,
       :styles => {
           :large => "524x257!",
           :xmedium => "435x330!",
           :medium => "329x152!",
           :thumb => "100x100!"
       },
       :storage => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
        :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension" 
 end
```

model 2:

```
class PromotionMenuPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base

        has_attached_file :photo,
       :styles => {
           :thumb => "50x50!"
       },
       :storage => :s3,
        :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml",
        :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension"
end
```

### tables

### promotion_photos

```
id | photo_file_name | photo_content_type |  photo_file_size
```

### promotion_menu_photos

```
id | photo_file_name | photo_content_type |  photo_file_size
```

problem:  if i upload promotions photo showing correct. But same photo display promotion_menus also. what is the wrong? can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have the same attachment path for both models:

`:path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension"`

In both models attachment name is `photo`.

Change attachment name or path in one of models.

Here is documentation for paperclip `has_attached_file`: [http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.4.5/Paperclip/ClassMethods:has_attached_file](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/2.4.5/Paperclip/ClassMethods%3ahas_attached_file)

Comment: thanks. how to change the path? ex: :path => ":model_name/:attachment/:id/:style.:extension"

Comment: In the path template you can use any method available from model. Just precede it by `:`